# Как в Android правильно определить дневное время?

Tags: android

Необходимо запускать в фоне AlarmManager, но только в дневное время. Вопрос - как правильно определить дневное время на момент запуска менеджера или ночное?

Comment: Получая системное время? 

```java
Date currentTime = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
```

Answer (score 1):

Для начала вам нужно определится с тем что есть дневное и ночное время, во сколько начинается дневное и ночное время, и создать в AlarmManager-е единоразовую задачу или циклическую на дневное время это примерно с 12:00 до 18:00, и на всякий случай, в сутках 24 часа, в 1-м часе 60 минут, в 1-й минуте 60 сек, а в 1-й сек 1000 миллисекунд.